# How to get the number of rows from nested table with Xpath?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the nested table below for which I want to store in a variable the number of rows in the second tbody.

The Xpath of main table and Xpath of the second table tbody are:

```
//*[@id="MainTable"]/table

//*[@id='MainTable']/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody
```

Testing in Chrome Console with the code below, I'm getting successfully the second tbody so far.

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
console.log( getElementByXpath("//*[@id='MainTable']/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody") );
```

But I'm stuck in how to get the number of rows for this second tbody.

May someone help to achieve this getting the number of rows for this tbody or a better way to do it? Thanks for any help.

This is the HTML structure:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id = "main">
                    <table id = "table_x">...</table>
                    <div>...</div>
                    <iframe>...<iframe>
                    <table class="table2_class" summary="MySummary">
                        <thead>...</thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="a1" >
                                <td class="td_class">1</td>
                                <td class="td_class">N</td>
                                <td class="td_class_1">
                                    <div dir="" class="zzz">
                                        <div class="div_class">
                                            <a href="...">Some text</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="b1" >
                                <td class="td_class">4</td>
                                <td class="td_class">W</td>
                                <td class="td_class_1">
                                    <div dir="" class="zzz">
                                        <div class="div_class">
                                            <a href="...">Some text</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr class="a1" >
                                <td class="td_class">7</td>
                                <td class="td_class">R</td>
                                <td class="td_class_1">
                                    <div dir="" class="zzz">
                                        <div class="div_class">
                                            <a href="...">Some text</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>            
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

This code it seems to work:

```
getElementByXpath("//*[@id='MainTable']/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody").rows.length
```